# Update property value as dependent property changes

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working on an Angular (5) app using TypeScript, and have come across a question I cannot seem to find the answer to. Please see the following example:

```
...
export class SomeComponent implements onInit {
    ...

    // Properties
    someProperty: string = null;
    isValid: boolean = this.someProperty !== null;
    ...

}
```

In the above case, `isValid` will be initialized to `false` as `someProperty === null` on initialization. I would like `isValid` to automatically update whenever `someProperty` updates and represent the correct boolean value depending on whether `someProperty` is null or not.

Having worked with React and its state previously, I foolishly assumed the above would work. However it doesn't seem to, and therefore I'm wondering what the correct TypeScript way of doing the above is?

Comment: Are you trying to describe an [*accessor*](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#accessors)? `get isValid() { return this.someProperty !== null; }` (or define a `set` on `someProperty` that updates `isValid`, I suppose). You're binding a *value*, not a *calculation*.

Comment: Great @jonrsharpe, that works! Please add this as a reply so I can mark accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature you're looking for is an [accessor](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#accessors), in this case a simple getter:

```
export class SomeComponent {

  someProperty: string = null;

  get isValid(): boolean {
    return this.someProperty !== null;
  }

}
```

That method will be called every time the `isValid` "property" is accessed.